# QuercusEngine does not support all Php code

Tags: java, php

```
package q;

import com.caucho.quercus.QuercusEngine;

/**
 *
 * @author Raymond(Home)
 */
public class Q {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    QuercusEngine engine = new QuercusEngine();
    engine.setIni("foo", "bar");
    engine.execute("<?php  $_objSmsProtocolGsm = new Com(\"ActiveXperts.SmsProtocolGsm\"); ?>");
    }
}
```

Here is my error

Exception in thread "main" com.caucho.quercus.QuercusErrorException: 'Com' is an unknown class name.
    at com.caucho.quercus.env.Env.error(Env.java:6904)
    at com.caucho.quercus.env.Env.createErrorException(Env.java:6476)
    at com.caucho.quercus.env.Env.createErrorException(Env.java:6459)
    at com.caucho.quercus.env.Env.findAbstractClass(Env.java:5547)
    at com.caucho.quercus.expr.ObjectNewExpr.eval(ObjectNewExpr.java:91)
    at com.caucho.quercus.expr.Expr.evalCopy(Expr.java:514)
    at com.caucho.quercus.expr.Expr.evalAssignValue(Expr.java:585)
    at com.caucho.quercus.expr.BinaryAssignExpr.eval(BinaryAssignExpr.java:88)
    at com.caucho.quercus.expr.Expr.evalTop(Expr.java:540)
    at com.caucho.quercus.statement.ExprStatement.execute(ExprStatement.java:67)
    at com.caucho.quercus.program.QuercusProgram.execute(QuercusProgram.java:414)
    at com.caucho.quercus.QuercusEngine.execute(QuercusEngine.java:159)
    at com.caucho.quercus.QuercusEngine.execute(QuercusEngine.java:116)
    at q.Q.main(Q.java:17)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to the php_com_dotnet.dll extension to enable Microsoft COM calls. Quercus has support for a limited number of extensions (among which are some of the most commonly used extensions like GD and PDO), however the COM extension isn't among these.

As a workaround, you may consider wrapping your functions inside a webservice to communicate with PHP.